# Split and Modify Last

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string “shared/errors”, and I’d like for the the word “error” to be prepended with an underscore, so as to achieve “shared/_errors” Is there some ruby magic for doing this?

Comment: How about `string = 'shared/_errors'`?

Comment: How about showing us the code you've written, along with the problem you're having getting it to work? See http://sscce.org/ for how to correctly supply us with the information we need to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is only a single slash in the string, all that is necessary is

```
string.sub!(%r|(?<=/)|, '_')
```

or, if you prefer,

```
string.sub!('/', '/_')
```

If there are multiple slashes in the string and you only want to affect the last one, then you want

```
string.sub!(%r|(?=[^/]*\z)|, '_')
```

Comment: What is the regex in the last example doing?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to do this on the last occurrence of the forward slash you can insert an underscore at the index of the slash:

```
string.insert(string.rindex('/') + 1, '_')
```

Comment: +1 beautiful, simple solution. Just what Ruby programming should feel like :)

Comment: Are you thinking of Python?  Ruby doesn't have `rfind`.  Using `rindex` instead, the underscore goes on the wrong side.

Comment: You're welcome!  Nice job on the quick fix; it all looks good to me now.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps all answers are valid here, but I did see that OP references 'errors' by name.  Rather than the slash.

`string.gsub!('error', '_error')` should change the original string, and do so, for all occurrences that may happen in the string.  Of course, I have a feeling the slash is important, so perhaps the more correct `string.gsub!('/error', '/_error')` will do better.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
path = 'shared/errors' # or whatever it is
dir, file = path.match(/^(.*\/)([^/]*)$/).captures
path = dir + "_" + file
```

This will get the two parts of the string:

```
shared/errors ==> shared/ + errors
```

And then patch them back together to form the desired string.